# SQL transforming from (+)= query to left outer join

Tags: sql, oracle, left-join, outer-join

**Query before transformation**

```
SELECT w.tech AS tech,
       w.wpcddate AS job_date,
       w.corp AS corp,
       w.house AS house_number,
       w.cust AS cust_number,
       h.zipcode AS zipcode
  FROM fsm_m_wipmaster w,
       fsm_m_zipmaster z,
       fsm_m_housemaster h,
       fsm_m_custmaster c
 WHERE c.corp(+) = w.corp
   AND c.house(+) = w.house
   AND c.cust(+) = w.cust
   AND h.corp(+) = w.corp
   AND h.house(+) = w.house
   AND h.cust(+) = w.cust
   AND z.corp(+) = w.corp
   AND z.zipbeg IS NULL
   AND h.zipcode IS NOT NULL
   AND w.tech IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY w.corp;
```

**Query After transformation**

```
SELECT w.tech AS tech,
       w.wpcddate AS job_date,
       w.corp AS corp,
       w.house AS house_number,
       w.cust AS cust_number,
       h.zipcode AS zipcode
  FROM fsm_m_housemaster h
       LEFT OUTER JOIN
       fsm_m_custmaster c
      ON h.cust = c.cust
     AND h.corp_seq = c.corp_seq
     AND h.house = c.house
       LEFT OUTER JOIN
       fsm_m_wipmaster w
      ON h.cust = w.cust
     AND h.house = w.house
     AND h.corp_seq = w.corp_seq
       LEFT OUTER JOIN fsm_m_zipmaster z
      ON h.corp_seq = z.corp_seq AND z.zipbeg IS NULL
 WHERE w.tech IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY w.corp;
```

I seem to break my head as to why the Query After transformation is not returning the same results as query before.
I know i am missing something silly here
Can anyone spot the obvious ?

Comment: The conditions `z.zipbeg is null`, `h.zipcode is not null` and `w.tech IS NOT NULL` don't use the `(+)` syntax, so they cannot be part of the ON clause but have to stay in the WHERE clause. If I'm not mistaken, they use of the `(+)` syntax didn't have any effect in the original query because these same conditions turn the outer joins into an inner joins. So what looked like an outer join has always been an inner join.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The original query only consists of a single outer join because the `(+)` hasn't been used on all conditions on the relevant tables.

So the correct rewrite using the newer join syntax is:

```
SELECT w.tech AS tech,
    w.wpcddate AS job_date,
    w.corp AS corp,
    w.house AS house_number,
    w.cust AS cust_number,
    h.zipcode as zipcode
FROM fsm_m_wipmaster w 
JOIN fsm_m_zipmaster z   ON z.corp = w.corp AND z.zipbeg is null
JOIN fsm_m_housemaster h ON h.corp = w.corp AND h.house = w.house AND h.cust = w.cust AND h.zipcode is not null
LEFT OUTER JOIN fsm_m_custmaster c  ON c.corp = w.corp AND c.house = w.house AND c.cust = w.cust
WHERE w.tech IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY w.corp;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try :

```
SELECT w.tech AS tech,
  w.wpcddate AS job_date,
  w.corp AS corp,
  w.house AS house_number,
  w.cust AS cust_number,
  h.zipcode as zipcode
FROM fsm_m_wipmaster w
LEFT OUTER JOIN fsm_m_zipmaster z ON w.corp = z.corp
LEFT OUTER JOIN fsm_m_housemaster h ON w.corp = h.corp AND w.house = h.house AND w.cust = h.cust
LEFT OUTER JOIN fsm_m_custmaster c ON w.corp = c.corp AND w.house = c.house AND w.cust = c.cust 
WHERE w.tech IS NOT NULL 
AND z.zipbeg IS NULL
AND h.zipcode IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY w.corp;
```

It seems that you inverted `JOINs` : in the first query, it's the `fsm_m_wipmaster` table which is on the left side of the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` (hence the `(+)` on the joined fields).

See [this](http://www.dba-oracle.com/tips_oracle_left_outer_join.htm).

Answer (score 1):

One reason may be that the revised query references a field called `z.corp_seq` and `h.corp_seq`, but the original query does not:

```
left outer join fsm_m_zipmaster z on  h.corp_seq = z.corp_seq  and z.zipbeg is null
```

Try this:

```
left outer join fsm_m_zipmaster z on  h.corp = z.corp  and z.zipbeg is null
```